# Drawing something on my LinearLayout?

Tags: android

I'm extending LinearLayout:

```
public class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);
    }
}
```

If the layout has child elements, shouldn't the red line above be drawn on top of them? Considering a layout like:

```
<MyLinearLayout>
    <ImageView />
</MyLinearLayout>
```

I'd expect to get the red line drawn above the child ImageView. But it gets drawn below it. I was assuming all child drawing would have been completed after the super.onDraw() line is finished.

Is there a way to get to the canvas and draw something on it after all child drawing has been completed?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Layouts don't draw unless you call `setWillNotDraw(false);`.  They do that for efficiency reasons.

**EDIT**:

`onDraw()` really is meant to just allow you to modify the `Canvas` before the drawing operation happens.  It doesn't actually draw.  What you want to do is override `draw()` like so:

```
@Override
protected void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);
}
```

Calling the super will draw all the children in the view.  Then it will draw all the lines.  I do still believe you need `setWillNotDraw(false)` to be called though.

Comment: I guess this is frowned upon.

Comment: Why? Did something happen?  It's only frowned upon in the sense that it will slow down your drawing operation ever so slightly.

Comment: Oh - the docs don't say how little or how much the performance impact is. I was just guessing it'd be pretty severe. I'll try looking around for some info.

Comment: Hmm actually ok I just tried this, calling setWillNotDraw(false) doesn't seem to have any effect - the canvas drawing still happens below all children.

Comment: Oh.  Sorry, I misunderstood your post.  Check my edit and see if this works.

Comment: oooohhh man! +1. I thought it was impossible for ViewGroups to draw over parents. I have performed a brutal optimization thanks to overriding draw() :)

Comment: Nice solution, but please initialize the Paint object outside of the draw() method... ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a LinearLayout and you need:

1. draw all of its children first, like buttons, image views
2. then, on top of those components, draw something directly on the canvas.

   You can try this:

   ```
   public class YourClass extends LinearLayout
   {
   @Override
   protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)
   {
       super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
   ```

   `// do your custom drawings afterwards

   canvas.drawCircle...
   canvas.drawLine...`

Answer (score 0):

I'm rewriting my answer as I hadn't seen your line of code where you were drawing to the canvas.

The canvas like some other graphics environments is inverted. So calling getHeight() is actually drawing the line at the bottom. Instead call

```
   canvas.drawLine( 0, 0, getWidth(), 0, paint);
```

This means draw the line at the top, across the width of the view.

Also, calling super first paints the children prior to any custom painting so your fine there.